# Why GCM messages not delivered today?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've a problem with GCM messages.
I've built an Android App and every day I sent from server some GCM messages to clients and all is ok.
This morning I've sent new messages and GCM server answered me that deliveries were ok but noone client received these messages.
And no errors from GCM Server.
Could be a GCM service problem ? ...in Google I mean...

Please help me, GCM messages are very important for my app :)

Comment: I solved it by myself, there was an error in the data i was sending to the clients and there was a problem deserializing it client side.
No problems with google GCM :)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever think that Google may be the issue you can head over to the support site and get help from there: https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support

Comment: Ok, thank you very much Danish for your suggestion :)